# Intersection polyline (not closed but maybe) and a ray JS or C++

Tags: javascript, c++, line, intersection, polyline

I searched here and in google but I didnt find a clear explanation specially in JS, it is complicated.

Let var polyline is a 2D array of the x and y values of each point of the polyline.

```
var polyline = [[xa,ya],[xb,yb],....,[xn,yn]];
```

and var centerPt is a array of the x and y value of a random chosen point

**Here it has been edited:**

```
var centerPt = [xctr,yctr];
//or
var centerPt = [[xctr,yctr]];
```

**xctr ist not xc, that is in the array polyline**

See figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGjJd.jpg) please.

and x,y values of many points represented also as 2D array

```
var edgePts = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...,[xmax,ymax]];
```

Let a each ray begins from the centerPt to a point of edgePts

```
//1st ray: from [xc,yc] to [x1,y1]
//2n ray: from [xc,yc] to [x2,y2]
// ...
// nth ray: from [xc,yc] to [xmax,ymax]
```

I would get ideas or links, to create a function e.g. `intersectRayPoly(ray,polyline)` that yields the intersection point x and y

Note: please without jQuery, pure JS or simple c++ are ok

Thanks in advance for each hint and sorry for grammatical errors, my english is not good :(

**Edited**:
A line AB has equation `y = mx +c` with `m   = (yB-yA)/(xB-xA)`
But here it is a ray, also **one** intersection, not **two** as it is the case of line

Comment: Representing lines with `y = mx+q` has problems with vertical lines (singularities) or quasi-vertical lines (accuracy). In most 2D computations the parametric equation `x = x0 + s*dx, y = y0 + s*dy` works much better. The `y=mx+q` works only for "1.5-dimensional" problems...

Comment: Thanks, I will take that into account

Answer (score 0):

The core of the problem is a function that given two segments `(xa, ya)-(xb, yb)` and `(xc, yc)-(xd, yd)` gives you back the intersection if there is one.

A simple approach is requires solving the linear system of two equations in two unknowns `s` and `t`

```
xa + s*(xb - xa) = xc + t*(xd - xc)
ya + s*(yb - ya) = yc + t*(yd - yc)
```

that in canonical form is

```
s*(xb - xa) + t*(xc - xd) = xc - xa
s*(yb - ya) + t*(yc - yd) = yc - ya
```

solving with Cramer rule

```
delta = (xb-xa)*(yc-yd) - (yb-ya)*(xc-xd)
s = ((xc-xa)*(yc-yd) - (yc-ya)*(xc-xd)) / delta
t = ((xb-xa)*(yc-ya) - (yb-ya)*(xc-xa)) / delta
```

If the system is not singular (`delta != 0`) and if both `s` and `t` are between 0 and 1 then you have a proper intersection point and the coordinates are:

```
x = xa + s*(xb - xa)
y = ya + t*(yb - ya)
```

When `delta` is 0 or when `s` or `t` are 0 or 1 you are on "edge" cases (e.g. partially overlapping segments, a segment touching the other, degenerates segments with start=end and so on) and you should decide first what you want to do in these cases.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good step, but I edited and posted an image. I think there was an missunderstanding isn't?

Comment: The blacks rays intersect always with the blue polyline/(or maybe polygone), these intersection points are searched for, to calcaulate them